# Normalize and Results show as Percentage

Tags: arcgis-10.3, normalize

I've Normalized my data and everything looks okay. However, its appearing (*on my map legend and in the Table of Contents*) as a ratio (**Ex: 0.000-0.005**) but I would rather it appear as a percentage (Ex: **0%-5%**). 
As an attempt at a solution, when I Right click on the layer property and Open Attribute table, there's no field in the table as NORMALISED DATA. Therefore, I'm having problems right clicking on that field, going to Numeric and changing it to percentage.

Note:
The process I used to generate my Normalised data (which is been shown as ratio) is this:

I went to symbology>Quantities>Graduated Colors and selected my first field for Value and my other field for Normalization. My Classes is 5.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

1. open attribute table
2. right click on the field that appears in the the legend
3. click numeric button
4. change to percentage
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. open attribute table
2. Add a numeric field
3. use field calculator and multiply your values with 100. You will have percentages this way but it will not show as something like %5 maybe you can rename your layer as %_layername
   Is your layer file is a shapefile ? if it is raster with continuous data, you need to use reclassify and raster calculator tools which is more complex than steps above. if you post a picture it would be easier to understand. Did you import your layer from external sources ? if it is make sure your column header does not have any space

Comment: The Normalized field doesn't appear in the Attribute Table. How do I make it show up in order to do the multiplication? I've included how I initially generated my Normalization data in my question.